# How to do vertical shrinking of subviews using autolayout when their superview is shrinking vertically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I would like to be enlightened on the idea: shrinking of superview which would result to automatic shrinking of its subviews also. I want to know how to do this in the Interface Builder.

Comment: Set some autolayout constraints?

Answer (score 0):

I still like to deactivate Autolayout for that. (select the View in the IB, in the utilities tab you go to the file inspector and uncheck the "Use Auto Layout") property.

Then:
 1. In the interface builder you select the subview.
 2. You go to the size inspector (2nd from right, looks like a ruler)

In the middle on the left you have a gray square with 2 arrows in the middle and 4 lines on the outside (The Autosizing box). By clicking them you can activate them (red) or deactivate them. The 4 lines on the outside represent the "stick to the superview". E.g. if you activate the red line on the right the subview will always keep its set distance to its superview. the arrows in the middle activate/deactivate horizontal/vertical autoresize.

So to make a subview stick to its superview in every direction and make it resize alongside you have to activate both arrows and all lines.